# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, методы

```
def registerpage1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        username = data.get('username')
        parol = data.get('password')
        jins = data.get('jinsi')
        name = data.get('name')
        surname = data.get('surname')
        name = data.get('name')
        location = data.get('location')
        about = data.get('about')
        phone = data.get('phone')
        email = data.get('email')
        telegram = data.get('telegram')
        instagram = data.get('instagram')
        telegram = data.get('telegram')
        image = request.FILES.get['imag']
        U = UserProfil.objects.create(jins=jins, ism=name, familiya=surname, joylashuv=location, textarea=about, tel=phone, mail=email,telegram_link=telegram,instagram_link=instagram,login=username,paroll=parol, userpic=image)
        U.save()
        try:
            User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            password=parol,
            first_name=first_name,
            )
        except:
            messages.error(request, f"<< '{username}' >>    Bunday turgadi login mavjut iltimos qayta urinib ko\'ring!! misol uchun(*/#$%@^%) qo'shimchalardan foydalaning ")
        return redirect('sign_in')
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Единственная строка, к которой может относиться ошибка `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable` в вашем коде, это та, где есть квадратные скобки:

```
image = request.FILES.get['imag']
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

`FILES` - это словарь, насколько я понимаю. Из словаря можно получить значение либо с помощью индексирования (квадратных скобок):

```
image = request.FILES['imag']
```

Либо с помощью метода `get` (обращение с помощью круглых скобок):

```
image = request.FILES.get('imag')
```